# How to enable scanning with feature: extendedScanAndConnect

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, ios13, bluetooth-5

I saw that started from iOS 13 we can scan for extended advertisement packet.

In Core Bluetooth documentation I have found:

```
class func supports(_ features: CBCentralManager.Feature) -> Bool 

static var extendedScanAndConnect: CBCentralManager.Feature { get }
```

but I don't know how to enable extended scanning?

Maybe it's set by default on devices which support it?

I can't even check even this because I don't have a device which are support it.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I inquired with Apple about this feature, this is the response I got from DTS:

> CBCentralManager.Feature.extendedScanAndConnect is what we call a
> dynamic feature, that changes from device model to device model, and
> can change as different radio chipsets could be getting used in
> different models, and support can be enabled or disabled depending on
> the iOS version.
>
> As such, we don’t have a list that you can use to determine whether it
> is supported or not. That’s why it is gated behind the
> supportsFeatures() call, so your app can dynamically determine on the
> device it runs on. If you wanted to test it, you can use an iPhone 13
> Pro, which does have support. But to actually be able to use the
> feature, the advertising peripheral must also support extended
> advertising and connections.
>
> The extended scan and connection is a link layer capability and does
> not enable anything different for your app. It is informative only to
> indicate that the iOS device will scan for and recognize extended
> advertising packets from the peripheral. The capabilities include
> longer advertising packets (254 bytes vs 31), chained advertising
> packets for longer data, synchronized advertising. Not all of these
> features are guaranteed to be enabled on every device/iOS
> combinations. Even if it returns YES or NO to the feature now, it is
> not guaranteed that the same device will return the same result in the
> future.
>
> The only behavior difference you might notice is the lack of the
> secondary didDiscover() callback for an advertisement if a SCAN_RSP
> packet for more data is deemed no longer necessary.